# Jquery autocomplete: after select (by mouse), automatically gives a space

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete, and now I need it to give a space right after the selection (by mouse).

I tried something like this:

```
$('input[id$=item_price_new]').val(price)+ " ";
```

but it doesn't work.

here is the story: i have a jquery autocomplete loads up item description and price, ie: Mouse 101/$3.99

in my form, there are 2 columns, one is item description, one is price. (autocomplete on the item description column) both input text field.

after few ask around, i am now able to show up price in the price field base on the selection in the item description:

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$('input[id$=item_new]').keyup(function() {
    var txtClone = $(this).val();
    var n = txtClone.lastIndexOf('/$');
    var price = txtClone.substr(n+2)
    //alert (n);
    $('input[id$=item_price_new]').val(price);
});
```

});//]]>

but this only happen when the user have to manually press SPACE bar after the selection of the item.

and i like to eliminate this manual step.

any ideas?

Comment: What you actually want to do? Can you please clarify yourself a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$('input[id$=item_price_new]').val($('input[id$=item_price_new]').val(price)+" ");`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add space at the end of the price? if yes, then see the code below,

```
$('input[id$=item_price_new]').val(price + ' ');
```

Are you able to handle the auto complete event?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value to anything with that code.

```
var myInput = $('input[id$=item_price_new]');
var oldValue = myInput.val();

// set the value to the old value with a space after it
myInput.val( oldValue + " " );
```